# Packages for Scatterplot in R

Tags: r

I am trying to use `scatterplot` function to plot a scatterplot. I have loaded packages like `ggplot2` and `scatterplot3d`. However, I get message, "`Could not find function scatterplot`". Further, when I plot using Rcommander, I see the same command, "`scatterplot`"

What package am I expected to load?

**Note** I know there is plot or some other functions using ggplot. I see that Rcmdr uses scatterplot command and it has some speciality like boxplot at side, etc. That is why I want to stick to it.

Comment: I am not familiar with any standard `scatterplot` function.  You can try `qplot(x,y,df)` or `xyplot(y~x,df)` or `plot(x,y)` depending on which graphics package you are using.

Comment: Thanks for your info. and may be I mistook some other commands below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for:

- [ScatterPlot:::lessR](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/lessR/html/ScatterPlot.html)
- [scatterplot.density:::aqfig](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/aqfig/html/scatterplot.density.html)
- [scatterPlot:::tis](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/tis/html/scatterPlot.html)
- [rp.scatterplot:::rapport](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/rapport/html/rp.scatterplot.html)
- [scatterPlot.HH:::RcmdrPlugin.HH](http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/R/library/RcmdrPlugin.HH/html/scatterPlot.HH.html)

Package `scatterplot3d` had only one function which is called... `scatterplot3d()`.

Comment: `car::scatterplot` is a common one. Also, don't you have your syntax reversed?  It's usually `package::function` rather than `function::package`

Comment: @BenBolker oh yes! My six-week old is making my brain go fudgy.