# How to plot a sequence of points?

Tags: r, point

All info I found so far about R deals with more complex cases than I have. And I have dead simple list of points in form of XY coordinates. Now I would like to plot them, something like:

```
plot(c(3.1,4.4),c(17.2, 5),c(13.0,7.1), ...)
```

How to do it?

*I chose R because it seems the easiest option for plotting such data.*

Comment: Take a look at `?plot`. There are a number of ways to do this, but you can pass a vector of x-coords followed by a vector of y-coords (`plot(c(3.1, 17.2, 13.0), c(4.4, 5, 7.1))`.

Comment: @jbaums, I need to pass data in a sequence of XY points without transforming them to a sequence of X's with Y's.

Comment: You can use separate x,y vectors or you may want to put your data in data.frame with x and y columns.

Comment: What do you mean "pass in"? Input argument to a function (why must it be that way?), or input from a file?

Comment: @smci, the nature of the work I have. I simply have such data (in such form), and any reordering just obscures the data for later comparison. Thus I have to stick to such sequence -- point 1, point 2, point 3, and not -- X of point 1, X of point 2, ... Y of point 1, Y of point 2.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scatterplot in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15322537/scatterplot-in-r)

Comment: @zx8754, the other question is about loading a module.

Comment: To get a dataframe (which is more useful), use rbind:  `data.frame(rbind(...)) `. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine your points into a matrix or data frame first.

```
data_points <- matrix(c(c(3.1,4.4),c(17.2, 5),c(13.0,7.1)), ncol = 2, byrow = T)
data_points
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]  3.1  4.4
#[2,] 17.2  5.0
#[3,] 13.0  7.1
plot(data_points[, 1], data_points[, 2])
```

Comment: "I need to pass data in a sequence of XY points without transforming them to a sequence of X's with Y's. –  greenoldman". This answer **is** transforming the data into X's n Y's.

Comment: @zx8754 Yes, that's true. Perhaps it is useful that you can pass in a sequence of points to `matrix` instead of to `plot`.

Comment: @zx8754, I mean by myself. Here the sequence (as you read it) is preserved exactly as it was in input -- sequence of points.

Comment: or see my answer for the `data.frame( rbind( ... ))` version.

Answer (score 1):

Get your data into two columns... x and y, for example. The same length would be good. Then try `plot(x,y)`

Answer (score 0):

You can either convert to a matrix or **dataframe**, as below.
Dataframe is much more generically useful, you can have other heterogeneous columns e.g. color, label, date, whatever.

```
# Create a dataframe fromm our x,y series
df <- data.frame( rbind(c(3.1,4.4),c(17.2, 5),c(13.0,7.1)) )
names(df) <- c('x','y')

# Now plot the two series with either of...
with(df, plot(x,y))
plot(df$x, df$y)
```